# "Класть" и "положить"

Tags: этимология, словообразование, орфоэпия

Вот подумалось: а почему существует два разных корня, обозначающих, в общем-то, одно действие? В смысле, "класть" и "положить". Понятно, что корень "-лож-" употребляется только с приставкой - грамматически все ясно. Но почему так вышло, что для одного действия появилось два разных слова?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Очень интересная эта пара класть-(с)ложить.
Но вопрос вы не совсем правильно ставите.
Певрое. Пара это уникальна для русского языка, на её примере ничего сказать об общих закономерностях русского языка нельзя. Нечто подобное можно найти, например, в паре идти - ходить, но там у составляющих несколько разное семантическое наполнение, наша же пара различается исключительно грамматикой.

Второе. Это никак не синонимы. Это явление скорее можно отнести к супплетивизму - образованию разных форм одного слова от разных корней, правда оно скорее относится к словоизменению, не к словообразованию.

Третье. Приставка здесь ни при чем. Хорошо известная нам *ложка* - форма родственная *ложить*, ложка - то, чем *ложат*. Зато *колода* родственна *складывать.*
Разделение же глаголов на формы с "клад" и "лож" идёт по линии грамматического вида: глаголы совршенного вида требуют "лож": сложить, выложить, наложить; несовершенного - "клад/класт": класть, складывать, выкладывать, накладывать. Сразу заметим, что современная категория грамматического вида сложилась в русском языке сравнительно недавно - не ранее XVI века.
Кроме того следует иметь в виду, что в близкородственных языках (украинском, например) такого четкого разделения по грамматической роли у этих глаголов нет. Всё это позволяет сделать вывод, что рассматриваемое явление сложилось в русском очень недавно.

Объяснение же этого явления разделения глаголов по грамматической функции следует искать не в в сфере *образования* синонимов, а наоборот, разделения их по значению.
Или более подробно. Как можно видеть из всего сказанного, в русском языке к какому-то времени сложилась пара "синонимов". В подавляющем большинстве случаев язык постеменно изживает полную синонимичность, происходит либо устаревание одного из "синонимов", либо разделение по значению. В нашем случае такое разделение произошло по линии грамматической роли - по грамматическому виду.

Comment: Есть такой глагол несовершенного вида, как "ложиться", что показывает нам, что постфикс тоже может сделать корень "лож".

Comment: Согласен, но здесь возратность, а она иногда сказывается на грамматике самым неожиданным образом. И ожидаемым тоже. Например, убивает переходность. 

Это так, мысли вслух. Четкого объяснения нормативности "ложиться" (а не "класться") я не вижу.

Answer (score 2):

Приставка - это не точный признак. Например, "снег ложится". Интересная статья, в которой отец объясняет сыну различие корней "клад" и "лож" в блоге "[Культура речи](http://govorprav.livejournal.com/tag/%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0)"

Answer (score 1):

Если я верно понимаю, Ваш вопрос сводится к вопросам: **как** и **зачем** в языке возникают *синонимы,* верно? Отвечу по порядку, но кратко. Синонимы образуются в основном благодаря расширению/сужению семантики слов, иноязычным заимствованиям и словообразовательным процессам в языке. Возникают они, во-первых, чтобы язык отражал расширяющиеся и углубляющиеся представления человека о действительности, во-вторых, чтобы делать наш язык богаче, а речь – выразительнее. Ответил? :)

Comment: Нет. Меня интересуют конкретно два этих слова. Они не отражают "расширяющиеся представления о действительности". Вряд ли человек с течением тысячелетий как-то изменил свои представления о процессе *положения* (или *кладки*?)))). Но почему-то к процессу придумано аж два разных корня.

Answer (score 1):

Вот на мой взгляд интересная [статья](http://ushan.org/ru/pages/notes/lozhu/). Там размышления как раз по заданному вопросу. И ещё напишу пару слов по поводу аналогий с украинским языком.

> **behemothus** *пишет*:
>
> Кроме того следует
> иметь в виду, что в близкородственных
> языках (украинском, например) такого
> четкого разделения по грамматической
> роли у этих глаголов нет. Всё это
> позволяет сделать вывод, что
> рассматриваемое явление сложилось в
> русском очень недавно.

Теоретически, в украинском словаре можно найти слово "ложити", но литературном языке, да и, пожалуй, в разговорном, больше используется слово "класти". Даже больше, чем в русском. Использую Ваш, **behemothus**, пример.

> глаголы совршенного вида требуют
> "лож": сложить, выложить, наложить;
> несовершенного - "клад/класт": класть,
> складывать, выкладывать, накладывать.

На украинском:

скласти, викласти, накласти;

класти, складати, викладати, накладати.

Comment: Ичто? Какой мой тезис вы хотите подтвердить?

>Теоретически, в украинском словаре...   
  
"Теоретически" я владею украинским свободно. Практически - похуже. )))

Статья, имхо, никакая. Рассуждения ни о чем заради ничего. Вернее - ради пары крассивых сравнений и ворспоминаний о трудном детстве в СССР.

Comment: *<<Ичто? Какой мой тезис вы хотите подтвердить?>>*
Если коротко, то так. Украинский язык близкородственный русскому. И там корень "класт" используется даже в тех словах, где в русском "лож".

Comment: Не возражаю. Я не выскащывался, ни за ни против. Смысл у меня был тот, что "русское" разделение не имеет аналогов даже в близкородственных. И, следовательно, не надо искать какого-то сокровенного смысла.

Answer (score 1):

ЛожИтся что-то может само или сам, а кладется всегда кем-то :)
Тут можно рассмотреть, относительно чего идет речь и все на свои места встанет.

Answer (score 0):

Интересно  другое.  Можно  разделить  употребление  этих  глаголов  в  зависимости  от  категории  вида  и  сказать  как  правильно  говорить.  Но  чем  объяснить  постоянное  неправильное  употребление  этой  пары.  Диалектным  влиянием ?  Или  неграмотностью ?

Comment: Незнанием правила, то бишь неграмотностью.

Comment: После  Фильма  " Доживём  до  понедельника " все, кажется, должны  уже  знать,  что  глагола  "ложить"  в  русском  языке  нет.  Но  народ,  оказывается,  не  знает  и  широко  этим  глаголом  пользуется. Устойчивую  ошибку  носителей  языка  в  слове,  входящем  в  активный  словарь  этого  языка,  трудно  объяснить  одной  неграмотностью.  Да  и  с  какой-нибудь  областью ( территорией ) связать  её  трудно.  Это  неправильное  словоупотребление  используется  повсеместно. Должно  быть  более  убедительное  объяснение  этого  явления.

Comment: Да просто это удобно: использовать один и тот же корень, а не два разных. Зачем же человек будет делать так, как неудобно? Разве что его приучили или ему важно соблюдать правила. Например, чтобы казаться интеллигентным. Снобизм, в общем ;-)))

Comment: Мне  тоже  так  кажется. Язык  стремится  избавиться  от  избыточности.

Comment: Важно понимать, что если огромное число носителей долгое время употребляют слово "ложить", то оно в языке есть и находится на своём месте, ни о какой ошибке здесь не может быть речи, ибо "литературная норма", словари и пр. — явление надъязыковое и искусственное, которое правила языка не устанавливает, а просто закрепляет и кодицифицирует.

Comment: Всю жизнь "ложил", а тут сын стал "шибко грамотным" и пытается меня "покласть". В языке постоянно появляются новые слова, и большинство будет говорить как удобно, а не как "правильно". И сомневаюсь, что академики переучат это большинство

Answer (score 0):

Только не упускайте из виду тот факт, что форма КЛАСТЬ вымирает, остаются только его производные, так что и в русском этот корень не особо прижился.

Comment: «Форма КЛАСТЬ» вымрет тогда, когда перестанут возводить кирпичные стены, делать асфальтовое и плиточное покрытия, приносить деньги в банки. То есть, никогда, даже когда будут на всё класть.

Comment: Марк, не знаю, кто там вымирает, но точно не форма.

Answer (score 0):

Хотя вопрос и старый, но до сих пор почему-то не отвеченный.
В целом в словарях ответ есть, но не совсем в явном виде. Например у Ушакова "***покласть, покладу, покладёшь, прош. вр. поклал, поклала, совер., что (прост.). Положить, уложить в несколько приемов.***" Если же их скомпилировать и формализовать, то класть и ложить обозначают разные действия. Кладем мы упорядоченное множество, а ложим единичный и неупорядоченный объект. 
Конечно встречаются места где области применения могут пересекаться (выложить вещи и выкладывать вещи), но и тут объектности против группы заметна т.к. выложим кучей при выкладывании "один к одному". Пересечение же их, наиболее вероятно, возникает в следствии унификации языка при абстрагировании базовых понятий(Например шуйца/десница -> десница -> рука). Ну а поскольку манипуляции очень разнообразные, то и процесс абстрагирования их глаголов до сих пор не завершен...