Корень слова ПОЛОЖИТЬ
Прочитав заголовок, вы уже думаете: «Что за вопрос? Конечно же -ЛОЖ-!».
«Большой универсальный словарь русского языка» Морковкина с вами согласен, как и 13 форумчан, ответивших на этот вопрос. А вот 14-й заглянул в словарь Тихонова, который считает, что корень — -ПОЛОЖ-! При этом в ЗАЛОЖИТЬ, РАЗЛОЖИТЬ, ОБЛОЖИТЬ, ПОДЛОЖИТЬ, ПРИЛОЖИТЬ, СЛОЖИТЬ, УЛОЖИТЬ Тихонов нашел-таки корень -ЛОЖ-.
Кроме «опечатка», есть ли какое-то рациональное объяснение такому делению у Тихонова?
То, что «глагола ЛОЖИТЬ не существует», не повод относить ПО- к корню — остальные приставки Тихонов почему-то выделил.
Можем для самопроверки построить «морфемный квадрат»:
ПОМЕНЯТЬ — ОБМЕНЯТЬ
ПОЛОЖИТЬ — ОБЛОЖИТЬ

Что доказывает наличие корня -ЛОЖ- в ПОЛОЖИТЬ.
Можете ли вы найти какие-то рациональные мотивы, которые могли подтолкнуть Тихонова к выделению корня -ПОЛОЖ-?

А что Тихонов, в Сети дается такой разбор  https://kartaslov.ru/разбор-слова-по-составу/положить  https://rootword.ru/положить   Так что не опечатка.

@Sharon, думаю, эти сайты основаны на Тихонове. Что делает мой вопрос еще актуальнее. Пора ПОЛОЖИТЬ конец распространению ошибки.

Вы серьезно?)  Но у Тихонова всё по уму, иначе бы ошибку давно бы нашли. Ведь логично считать  именно так?

@Sharon Абсолютно серьезно. А что, мое доказательство наличия корня -ЛОЖ- вас не убедило? У вас есть аргументы в пользу корня ПОЛОЖ-? С удовольствием их выслушаю, в этом и смысл вопроса.

У меня есть твердое убеждение в том, что Тихонов всегда прав) Но не все наши участники так думают. // Доказательства? А вы ведь не особенно верите моим доказательствам, судя по предыдущей теме ваших вопросов. // У меня есть некоторые соображения на этот счет. Может, еще кого послушаем, хотелось бы по крайней мере) //А это ваши единомышленники, тоже недовольные словарем Тихонова ) https://vk.com/wall1441365_289

Обсуждение похожей темы: наследовать, корень СЛЕД или НАСЛЕД?  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/476337/Актуальное-морфемное-членение/476339#476339

А вот самое новое издание Морфемно-орфографического словаря Тихонова 2002 год  http://rus-yaz.niv.ru/doc/dictionary/morphemic-orthographic/fc/slovar-207-8.htm#zag-57530  полож/и́/ть(ся).  Тоже с опечатками?

Еще глагол нашелся: налож/и/ть. Как это объяснить? Никак приставки НА и ПО не вписываются в морфемный квадрат)  А почему?

Сергей, добро пожаловать на "Русский язык СЕ"!
Тихонов не находил корней, он находил что-то близкое к деривату или то, что называл, вроде как, словообразовательное гнездо. Словообразовательное гнездо - это слово, от которого некоторые другие слова являются производными.
Корень - это не всегда слово, но это основа слова несущая идею заключенную во всех слова имеющих данный корень, в том числе и во всех группах словообразовательных гнезд, имеющих данный корень.
Корень, не всегда неизменен. Корень ЛОЖ может иметь формы, ЛАГ, ЛЕЖ, ЛЕЧ, ЛОГ и тп. Все слова содержащие эти корни будут связанны одной идеей.

Корень слова - в индоевропейских языках главная часть слова,
повторяющаяся неизменно или с незначительными изменениями в целом ряде
родственных этимологически (т. е. схожих в звуковом отношении и
близких по значению) слов. К., при этом, является носителем главной
идеи слова, в то время как префиксы (см.) и суффиксы (см.) выражают
побочные понятия, связанные с главным, или "оттенки" значения... Брокгауз и Эфрон.

Как видно, БиЭ четко раздели, корень - ИДЕЯ, ГЛАВНОЕ, все остальные морфемы же отвечают за ЗНАЧЕНИЕ. Корень за значение не отвечает, поэтому и отдельным словом ему быть не обязательно.
*Сам Тихонов никогда не называл словообразовательные гнезда корнями. Это ему приписывает Википедия.
Относительно собственно слова ПО/ЛОЖ/И/ТЬ:

ЛОЖИТЬ (также лагать), класть, укладывать, употреб. только с
предлогами. Даль.

Думаю, снимает вопросы даже относительно словообразовательного гнезда.

"Корень за значение не отвечает"? Приехали...

"Тихонов не находил корней" – вы, вероятно, имеете в в иду «Словообразовательный словарь» Тихонова. Я же говорю про его «Морфемно-орфографический словарь».

Спасибо за ваше мнение относительно морфемного членения глагола ПОЛОЖИТЬ. Я его разделяю. Однако, мой вопрос в другом — какая логика подтолкнула Тихонова к разборам полож/и/ть, за/лож/и/ть? Почему в одном случае выделяется приставка, в другом нет?

@SergeySlepov ""Корень за значение не отвечает"? Приехали..."  Я постарался уйти от собственного мнения и опереться на источники, хотя я считаю так же. Если БиЭ писали, что корень не отвечает за "значение", у них были на это основания. Другое дело, что одно из основных направлений современного языкознания рассматривает язык слов как набор значений, но если брать шире и в общем, значением слово не ограничено. Хотя если рассматривать язык как функциональную часть, то нужно, вероятно, опираться на значения слов.

"Морфемно-орфографический словарь" - https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://nsportal.ru/sites/default/files/2022/07/09/tihonov_a.n._slovoobrazovatelnyy_slovar.pdf&embedded=true вот то, что я нахожу, там на обложке и далее в начале написано, что рассматриваются именно "словообразовательные гнезда, то есть корни слов которые "обросли суффиксами" и видимо префиксами.

Почему в одних случаях на ресурсах выделяют приставку отдельно, а на других нет, не могу сказать, это нужно обращаться к составителям ресурсов или редакторам словарей. Я отвечал на ваш тезис в заглавии, поэтому отметил, что корень и словообразовательное гнездо это не эквивалентные понятия. В случае с гнездами могут возникать разночтения, и в одном случае выделяться корень и др морфема вместе, а в другом отсекаться, это как карта ляжет, кому какая цепочка дериватов покажется растущей из одного гнезда.

Однако, как я понимаю, система нахождения слов с похожими значениями нужна для создания языковых профилей например лингвистических программ ИИ, и тут уже будет разница, включили вы группу слов без приставок в родственные или нет. То есть если слово "ложить" сейчас не употребимо, то есть другие слова близкие, например, "ложа". Кроме того дериват рассматривается не только через гнезда, но и через сематическую близость значений не однокоренных слов, например, положить-оставить могут быть синонимичными и заменять друг друга в ряде случаев.

Поэтому ваш второй вопрос сводится к задаче: а зачем нам нужно выделять или не выделять приставку отдельно от корня? Нужно ли нам расширять гнездо или сужать? То есть к вопросу функционала. Если вы знаете ответ на этот вопрос, у вас не должно возникать проблемы с морфемным членением. Мне кажется, как-то так.

У слова "положить" корень -лож-. Соответственно разбор по составу будет:

по/лож/и/ть

Почему?

В русском языке существуют однокоренные со словом "положить" слова: "вложить", "заложить", "переложить" и т. д.

Приставка по- в слове "положить" семантична. Её семантика такая же, как и в словах "по/став/и/ть", или "по/мест/и/ть", или даже "по/крас/и/ть". В данном случае приставка по- (по Ефремовой):



Образует глагол совершенного вида со значением доведения до результата.

Путаница может возникнуть в связи с тем, что корень -лож- в современном русском литературном языке является связанным. Соответственно слова "положить", "вложить", "заложить", "переложить" и т. д. будут относиться к различным словообразовательным гнёздам — общего предка у них нет. На этот случай во введении к двухтомному словарю Тихонова, Александр Николаевич оставляет комментарий:

Непроизводными являются также слова с связанным корнем, хотя они и
вычленяют в составе основы, кроме корня, полноценные
словообразовательные аффиксы (суффиксы, префиксы). Ср.: в/прячь и
вы/прячь. Однако, несмотря на наличие в основе таких слов
деривационных аффиксов, они не относятся к производным, так как в
современном русском языке у них нет производящих, т. е. ни от какого
другого слова они не образованы.

Можно сравнить обсуждаемый глагол "по/лож/и/ть" со словом "искусственн/ый", которое не является однокоренным со словом "искусств/о". В первом буквенное сочетание енн не выделяется в качестве суффикса ровно по той причине, что здесь у потенциального суффикса нет семантики. Если рассуждать в рамках модели А. Н. Тихонова.
И опять же, З. А. Потиха в своём словаре приводит другое членение:

искус/ств/о, искус/ств/енн/ый

Которое верно и имеет право на существование в рамках другой модели и другого словаря, составленного с другими целями.

Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

@Денис Кулагин  Смотрю Карту слов:  с/лож/и/ть, раз/лож/и/ть, но: полож/и/ть, налож/и/ть.  Как это объяснить? И опять в героях проблемные приставки ПО и НА.  Никак они не вписываются в морфемный квадрат)

@Sharon Для исправления такого рода неточностей, если они подтвердятся авторитетными бумажными словарями, нужно работать со всем словообразовательным гнездом, а в данном случае — с целым семейством гнёзд. Пока этого не сделано, и есть непоследовательность в разборах.

А вы сами считаете, что здесь везде надо выделять корень ЛОЖ, а глаголы с приставками ПО и НА вписываются в морфемный квадрат?  То есть в них нет ничего особенного?  Я вот так не считаю, но мне очень интересно именно ваше мнение)  // Кстати, мне очень помогает ваша Карта слов, и я постоянно с ней работаю, когда нужны примеры предложений) Спасибо!

@Sharon Моё мнение такое, что корень везде -лож-. Вот ещё один аргумент в пользу такого решения. Можно сравнить с разбором глагола на/клад/ыва/ть, который согласно толковому словарю отличается от глагола наложить только видом. За переключение вида в данном случае отвечает суффикс; приставка отвечает за нюанс действия, общий для обоих глаголов. Так как же получается, что в одном случае приставка выделяется, а в другом — нет. Это ещё один пример непоследовательности в разборах.

Спасибо за ваше мнение, пока отличающееся от словаря Тихонова в Сети.  Если это, конечно, истинный словарь, соответствующий его окончательной точке зрения (а мнения лингвистов тогда менялись).  Тем важнее подтвердить правильное решение специалистами РАН, а иначе никаких изменений в Сети не будет.   Что касается видовых пар, то глаголы многозначные, и отношения между класть, наложить, положить и др. нужно учитывать согласно толковому словарю.   А там не всё просто  https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=наложить&mode=slovari&dicts[]=42    https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=класть&mode=slovari&dicts[]=42

Учитывая все это, я стараюсь по возможности придерживаться официальной точке зрения при морфемном разборе, да и вообще в грамматике, так как решение зависит от многих факторов. А это под силу только специалистам.


…А вот 14-й заглянул в словарь Тихонова, который считает, что корень — ПОЛОЖ-!
При этом в ЗАЛОЖИТЬ, РАЗЛОЖИТЬ, ОБЛОЖИТЬ, ПОДЛОЖИТЬ, ПРИЛОЖИТЬ, СЛОЖИТЬ, УЛОЖИТЬ Тихонов нашел-таки корень -ЛОЖ-.
Кроме «опечатка», есть ли какое-то рациональное объяснение такому делению у Тихонова?

К сожалению, в «Морфемно-орфографическом словаре» Тихонова, в котором действительно не выделена приставка в слове ПОЛОЖИТЬ, много опечаток… К ним стоит отнести и эту.
Любые «рациональные» объяснения якобы невыделения Тихоновым приставки в слове ПОЛОЖИТЬ (со значением КЛАСТЬ) можно опровергнуть другими его словарями.
Так, в двухтомном «Словообразовательном словаре русского языка» Тихонова слово ПОЛОЖИТЬ, будучи исходным (= непроизводным) и возглавляющим соответствующее гнездо, снабжено отсылкой «ср. вложить, заложить и др.», означающей, что данное слово желательно анализировать на фоне сопоставляемых с ним слов.
Из раздела «Как пользоваться словарем»:

Общей частью (= корнем) слов ПОЛОЖИТЬ, ВЛОЖИТЬ, ЗАЛОЖИТЬ является именно ЛОЖ, и разбирать слово ПОЛОЖИТЬ по Тихонову следует так: по/лож/и/ть.
Такое же морфемное строение слова ПОЛОЖИТЬ приводит Тихонов и в своём «Словаре-справочнике по русскому языку» (М., 1997):

по/лож/и/ть (ср.: в/лож/ и/ть, за/лож/и/ть).

См. статью КЛАСТЬ из этого словаря:

Для справки: в этом словаре морфемный состав даётся после приведения словообразовательной структуры слова.

МАТЕРИАЛЫ ПО ТЕМЕ
Из учебника Литневской
Морфемика и словообразование — разные разделы языкознания.

МОРФЕМИКА стр. 12

Морфемика — раздел языкознания, в котором изучается система морфем языка и морфемная структура слов и их форм.
В морфемике решаются два основных вопроса:

как классифицируются морфемы русского языка,
как слово членится на морфемы, то есть каков алгоритм морфемного членения.

При морфемном разборе слова (разборе слова по составу) сначала в слове выделяется окончание и формообразующий суффикс (если они есть), подчёркивается основа.
После этого основа слова разбивается на морфемы.
Возможны два противоположных подхода к морфемному членению основы: формально-структурный и формально-смысловой. стр. 19

СЛОВООБРАЗОВАНИЕ, стр. 21

Предмет и основные понятия словообразования, стр. 20
Словообразование — раздел языкознания, в котором изучается формально-смысловая производность слов языка, средства и способы словообразования.
Главные задачи словообразования как раздела языкознания таковы:

установить, является ли слово производным в современном языке (на синхронном уровне),
определить, от чего и как образованно данное производное слово.

Словообразовательный разбор слова  стр. 23

СЛОВАРИ

Лексикология и лексикография, стр. 24
Лексикология — раздел языкознания, изучающий слово как единицу словарного состава языка (лексики) и всю лексическую систему (лексику) языка. Лексикография — теория и практика составления словарей.
Отражение морфемного состава слова и его словообразовательных отношений в словарях  стр. 24
Существуют специальные частные (аспектные) словари, отражающие морфемный состав слова и его словообразовательную производность.
Для работы с морфемным составом слова существуют словари, описывающие сочетаемость и значение морем (А. И. Кузнецова, Т. Ф. Ефремова «Словарь морфем русского языка», Т. Ф. Ефремова «Толковый словарь словообразовательных единиц русского языка»).
Словообразовательные отношения между словами отражены в словообразовательных словарях, наиболее полным из которых является «Словообразовательный словарь русского языка» А. Н. Тихонова в 2-х томах.
В этих словарях по алфавиту расположены непроизводные слова, к которым построены словообразовательные цепочки, учитывающие все производные этой непроизводной основы. Непроизводное слово со всеми его производными называется словообразовательным гнездом.

О словарях Тихонова

Огромны заслуги А.Н.Тихонова в создании гнездовых словообразовательных словарей.
В 1978 г. вышел первый в нашей лексикографии гнездовой «Школьный словообразовательный словарь русского языка» (с тех пор он выдержал уже 5 переизданий), а в 1985 г. — первый большой гнездовой «Словообразовательный словарь русского языка» в 2-х томах.
В них раскрыта словообразовательная структура производных слов: показано, на базе какого производящего и при помощи каких словообразовательных средств они образованы. В двухтомном «Словообразовательном словаре» А.Н.Тихонова более 145 тысяч слов.
Исследования А. Н. Тихонова обогатили учение о морфеме, о морфемном составе слова. Большой вклад в развитие морфемики внес «Морфемно-орфографический словарь» (1996; 2002), в котором впервые отражено морфемное строение значительного массива русской лексики (около 100 000 слов).
А это словарь Потиха З. А. Школьный словарь строения слов русского языка. Первое издание 1987 года. Он скорее соответствует формально-структурному принципу  морфемного анализа.

К сожалению, в «Морфемно-орфографическом словаре» Тихонова, 
в котором действительно не выделена приставка в слове 
ПОЛОЖИТЬ, много опечаток… К ним стоит отнести и эту. 

Неужели правда? Тогда это открытие века!
Наконец истина найдена 14-м участником!  Тогда нужно писать в РАН, в Министерство образования, обращаться во все структуры! Ведь всё пространство пользователей русского языка обучается по неправильным словарям Тихонова, где полно опечаток.
Да у него, видимо, там таких опечаток воз и маленькая тележка! А куда смотрят издатели словарей? Что же, энтузиасты-любители должны их контролировать?
Кстати, какое значение у приставки ПО в слове положить? Это надо обязательно выяснить! Предварительно!  И тогда со специалистами из Онлайн-школы Фоксфорд проконсультироваться.  Вот что они пишут про приставку ПО в слове понять, где тоже выделен связанный корень, в статье Уникальные морфемы. Связанные корни. Унификсы
Так, в группе отнять, поднять, принять, разнять приставки 
имеют конкретные пространственные значения и осмысляются 
четко. В глаголе же понять значение приставки неясно, 
поэтому нет оснований и для выделения в этом глаголе 
связанного корня.

Нет оснований? Ну это как сказать. Вот другая точка зрения:
 Любые «рациональные» объяснения якобы невыделения 
 Тихоновым приставки в слове ПОЛОЖИТЬ (со значением 
 КЛАСТЬ) можно опровергнуть другими его словарями.

И вот еще вопрос: почему нет новых изданий словарей Тихонова? Где сейчас разыщешь эти старые словари 1997 года?. А  большой гнездовой «Словообразовательный словарь русского языка» в 2-х томах вообще 1985 года!
Это недоработка Министерства образования! Издательства печатают все что угодно, но только не нужные народу книги! Вот, например, Тихонов А.Н. Школьный словообразовательный словарь, изд. АЙРИС-пресс, 2022. Нет там глагола положить.
Да, надо принимать решительные меры! Может, на словарь З. А, Потиха уж перейти? Старенький, но надежный. Как раз для пользователей подойдет. Но там тоже новых изданий что-то не видно.
Ведь до чего хорош формально-структурный метод анализа слов! С него начинается обучение детей с 3-го класса. Зачем нам больше-то?
РЕКОМЕНДАЦИЯ (для составителей учебных программ)
Желательно основной курс раздела "Морфемика и словообразование" изучать по  словарю З. А Потиха, а Морфемно-орфографический словарь  Тихонова, а также основы формально-семантического анализа (с учетом словообразования) отнести  к факультативному курсу в классах  с углубленным изучением языка.
ВЫВОД ПО ТЕМЕ
 Но вот, мой милый, чем тревожусь я... 

Зачем нам вообще все эти  разборки, противостояние словарей и методов анализа? Кому нужны здесь открытия?
Словообразование — наука во многом условно-формальная (договорная), и базовых знаний по этой теме вполне хватило бы. Уж если говорить о словарях, то следовало бы больше внимания уделять этимологическим словарям, там может быть особый интерес для понимания языка и его истории.
Там,  в сравнительном языкознании, истинная поэзия и нужные сведения. А еще возможность увидеть взаимосвязь времен и народов, которые когда-то были едины. А потом  Бог смешал людям языки и рассеял по всей Земле, а Вавилонская башня так и осталась недостроенной...

Sharon, Вашему восклицанию «Неужели правда? Тогда это открытие века!» могу только удивляться! Ну какое же это открытие… Вы, видимо, недостаточно внимательно читаете чужие ответы (да порой и свои ), коли не обратили внимание хотя бы на эту часть ответа Справочного бюро Грамоты. ру, поддержавшего мою точку зрения в вопросе о морфемном строении слов запас, запасать, запасти: Более того, можно предположить, что в «Морфемно-орфографическом словаре» А. Н. Тихонова содержится опечатка или ошибка… Ссылку на то наше обсуждение дам ниже, здесь она не поместилась.

https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474051/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C

Да удивляйтесь, ваше право) Я же приветствую ваши изыскания в своем новом ответе, разве не заметили))  И дневников, как вы, не веду, живу сегодняшним днем и новыми ВПЕЧАТЛЕНИЯМИ, так что зачем мне ваши ссылки. "Каждый день передо мной даль иная, Где я буду через час, я не знаю,.."  Но спасибо за внимание))

Теперь будем вместе бороться против Тихонова!) У нас много единомышленников – в этой теме и вообще! Будете нашим флагманом. Я охотно присоединюсь к вашей партии, если она победит))  // Потому что нет в этом выборе высокой науки, а есть договорные отношения (по какому словарю надо работать пользователям). Нехорош Тихонов, так выберем Потиху. А Тихонова пусть филологи изучают.


Корень ЛОЖ является связанным.

О связанных корнях
Связанным называется корень, употребляющийся в слове только со словообразовательными аффиксами. Например, можно привыкнуть и отвыкнуть, но нельзя употребить этот глагол вообще без приставки.
Нередко в семантике целого слова значение связанного корня является неясным, ощущается слабо. Мы видели это в глаголах обуть и разуть, имеющих связанный корень -у-. Вот еще примеры: отнять — отнимать, поднять — поднимать, снять — снимать, принять — принимать.
В этих словах значение приставок осознается четко, а значение связанного корня (-ня- в сов. в., -ним- в несов. в.) едва ощутимо. Что означает этот корень? Какое-то действие, но какое именно — неясно.
Выделение связанных корней обоснованно лишь тогда, когда прочие части слова являются морфемами, имеющими в составе слова определенное, четко осознаваемое значение: во-нз-и-ть, про-нз-и-ть (сравним: во-ткнуть, проткнуть), до-бав-и-ть, от-бав-и-ть (сравним: до-ли-ть, отли-ть); от-верг-ну-ть, в-верг-ну-ть (откинуть, от-бросить, в-ставить).
Если значение «соседей» неясно, нет оснований для вычленения и связанного корня. Так, в группе отнять, поднять, принять, разнять приставки имеют конкретные пространственные значения и осмысляются четко. В глаголе же понять значение приставки неясно, поэтому  связанный корень не выделяется.

В нашем случае картина аналогичная.

Значения приставок в приведенном списке глаголов понятно, кроме глагола положить. Какое же значение у этой приставки?
  ПО.., приставка. I. Служит для образования глаг. 7. Вносит 
  зн. достижения результата действия. Поблагодарить, 
  погибнуть, подарить, познакомить, покраснеть, потонуть, 
  поцеловать.

Другими словами, с помощью этой приставки образуются глаголы совершенного вида, а другой семантики там нет. Этим глагол  положить отличается от тех глаголов, где приставка также служит для образования совершенного вида, но кроме того выражает  значение определенной направленности действия.

Из этого следует однозначный вывод: в глаголе  положить значение приставки чисто грамматическое, поэтому нет оснований для выделения в этом глаголе связанного корня ЛОЖ.

Разбор по составу:  полож/и/ть.

"В глаголе положить значение приставки чисто грамматическое, поэтому нет оснований для выделения в этом глаголе связанного корня ЛОЖ." — В приведенных вами примерах: поблагодарить,  погибнуть, подарить, познакомить, покраснеть, потонуть, поцеловать значение приставки ПО- точно такое же, однако Тихонов нашел основания для ее выделения. Почему не в ПОЛОЖИТЬ?

"Связанным называется корень, употребляющийся в слове только со словообразовательными аффиксами." Есть просторечное ЛОЖИТЬ и существительное ЛОЖЕ 'место для лежания/сна'. Целых два слова без аффиксов с тем же корнем, что в ПОЛОЖИТЬ и очевидной смысловой связью.

Вы смешиваете слова со свободными и связанными корнями.  У Литневской дается определение связанных корней стр. 13, и корень ЛОЖ относится по этому определению к связанным . Просторечную лексику учитывать не стоит,  а ложе от лежать, а не от ложить.  Вы переходите на частные случаи для доказательства своей точки зрения)  // Еще особенность глагола: супплетивная видовая пара класть – положить. Все эти признаки отдаляют "положить" от остальных глаголов, неужели это не очевидно?

Ну и разные принципы морфемного анализа вы тоже не учитываете, считая формально-структурный метод единственно верным. Но вот Тихонов в своем «Морфемно-орфографическом словаре» (1996; 2002) счел возможным это учесть. Но ваша позиция мне понятна: так считают и многие пользователи русского языка, например: https://otvet.mail.ru/question/63591800

Обсуждение видовой пары класть - сложить https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/1112/Класть-и-положить  Этимология класть  https://vk.com/wall-89306387_28607

"В русском языке нет слова «ложить», и укрепившаяся речевая традиция этого не изменит (во всяком случае пока)". А то можно еще и ложку вспомнить, а не только ложе.  // Кстати, в словаре Потиха ваш вариант, так что вы не одиноки.

Уважаемая @Sharon, я не пытаюсь отстоять какую-либо точку зрения. Я пытаюсь понять логику Тихонова, вернее, ваше ее объяснение. Спасибо, что помогаете мне в этом.

Вы пишете: "в группе отнять, поднять, принять, разнять приставки имеют конкретные пространственные значения и осмысляются четко. В глаголе же понять значение приставки неясно, поэтому связанный корень не выделяется."
Мне неясно понятие "неясно". Чем "понять" неяснее чем "занять", например? Кстати, Тихонов не выделяет приставок ни в одном из глаголов на -нять. Так что ваше объяснение мне непонятно.

"В нашем случае картина аналогичная." В гнезде *нять Тихонов не выделил ни одной приставки, а в *ложить - везде, кроме ПОЛОЖИТЬ. В ПОНЯТЬ вы увидели "неясное" значение приставки, а в ПОЛОЖИТЬ - вполне ясное, грамматическое. В чем тогда аналогия?

Здравствуйте уважаемый  Сергей.  Спасибо вам за внимание к моему ответу.  Приставка ПО особенная, ее значение надо смотреть в словаре. Выберем значение 7. Вносит зн. достижения результата действия. Поблагодарить, погибнуть, подарить. Достижение результата действия близко к чисто грамматическому значению глаголов совершенного вида. Такое грамматическое значение есть у большинства приставок в русском языке (они обычно меняют вид глагола), но при этом они дополнительно обозначают определенную семантику.

Именно этим выделяется приставка ПО; кроме того, глагол положить образует видовую пару с глаголом класть. Разве это не повод, чтобы увидеть в слове положить нечто особенное и отличное от глаголов с другими приставками.
О морфемных квадратах: положить — обложить? Но это не так. У приставки ОБ явно просматривается значение "положить вокруг".
